# Determine the interior, exterior and boundary of Q∪(−∞,2]

Tags: real-analysis

I am having difficulty piecing this together. I know that the interior of Q is the empty set but with the union part it is quite confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is just a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so split it into $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\leq2\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x>2\}$.

Then the union of a set with one of its subsets is just itself, so the set you're looking at is
$$\left(-\infty,2\right]\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x>2\}$$
which is a *disjoint* union.

You can take it from here, analyzing both pieces separately (take care at exactly $x=2$).

Comment: thank you @obscurans

Comment: No problem - system works this way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers